# Show that if $\sum x_n y_n$ converges for all $y=\{y_n: n\}$ in $\ell_2$ , then $x=\{x_n :n\}$ is in $\ell_2$.

Tags: analysis

Show that if $\sum x_n y_n$ converges for all $y=\{y_n: n\}$ in $\ell_2$ , then $x=\{x_n :n\}$ is in $\ell_2$.

I am not able to go anywhere with this problem. Please help

Comment: Sorry, unreadable.

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61458/8271

Comment: First show that the sequence $x_{n}$ is bounded. Now use the Riesz representation theorem.

Answer (score 2):

First show that the sequence $x_{n}$ is bounded. If not, then for any $j$ there is $x_{n_{j}}>2^{j}$. Now take $y_{m}=2^{-k}$ if $m=n_{k}$ for some $k$ and $y_{m}=0$ otherwise. Then $\sum x_{n}y_{n} > \infty$, a contradiction. So we get $x_{n}$ is bounded.

Now we got that $L(y)=\sum x_{n}y_{n}$ is a bounded linear functional on $l^{2}$. Use the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: I don't know hoe to show that it is a bounded linear functional.