# Why should we use the uniform boundedness principle here?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Here is the question:

Let $A = [a_{ij}]_{i,j = 1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite matrix of real numbers and suppose that, for any $x \in \ell^2,$ the sequence $Ax$ belongs to $\ell^2.$ Prove that the operator $T,$ defined by $T(x) = Ax,$ is a bounded operator on $\ell^2.$

**My question is:**

I got a hint to use the uniform boundedness principle here but I do not know why, could anyone explain this to me, please? what makes me when I look at a problem to decide that it should be solved by UBP?

**EDIT:**

1-I have taken this proposition: "The series $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} a_{n} b_{n}$ converges absolutely for every convergent sequence $\{b_{n}\}$ iff $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} |a_{n}|$ converges." will it be helpful here in our case? the problem is that here in our case we are in $l^2.$

2-Also, Should it be better to use the uniform boundedness principle or the following theorem to solve the problem given above?

**Theorem:**

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and let $\{T_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $T$ be operators in $\mathcal{L}(X,Y).$ then $\lim_{n} T_{n}x = Tx,$ for all $x \in X,$ iff

(a)the sequence $\{T_{n}\}$ is bounded;

(b)lim_{n} T_{n}x exists on a dense subset of $X.$

Comment: Let $A_n$ be the top-left $n\times n$ matrix (zeroing out everything else), then for each $x$, $\sup_n \|A_n x\|_2 < \infty$ and by the uniform boundedness principle, $\sup_n \|A_n\| < \infty$. Finally note that $Ax$ is the pointwise limit of $A_nx$.

Comment: @user58955 could you provide more details, please? Also, what about my question above? How do I know that I should apply UBP?

Comment: Such questions are usually hard to answer. There is really no protocol. So, you want to show that $\|Ax\|$ is uniformly upper bounded for all unit vectors $x$. Now you are dealing with infinite sums and you need to use the fact that $Ax\in \ell^2$ for all $x$. Thus you may need to use special $x$'s to get something. It is a typical idea to approximate $A$ by finite-rank matrices (if you are taking a functional analysis course, you will see more examples like this when you're studying compact operators)...

Comment: and here the easiest thing to do is to take $n\times n$ submatrix, corresponding to taking $x$ with only finitely many nonzero coordinates. Then you will see that UBP helps.

Comment: why I should use special $x'$s and to get what? @user58955

Comment: This is what is ad hoc. You plug in special values of $x$ to obtain something for the purpose of the problem. Here, since you have a $\ell_2$ sequence, it is again a typical attempt to approximate $x$ (which may consist of infinitely many nonzero coordinates) by its finite truncations: $(x_1,0,0,0,\dots), (x_1,x_2,0,0,\dots), (x_1,x_2,x_3,0,\dots)$. It may work and it may not work. But you can try that and see what you get afterwards.

Comment: I got a hint to define $$T_{N}x = (\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{ij}x_{j})$$ is this the same idea you are trying to convey to me? @user58955

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same as what I said.

Comment: where is the truncation here? I can not see it. where is taking $x$ with finitely many nonzero terms?I can not see this in this hint.@user58955

Comment: How can I verify that this $T_N$ is bounded?@user58955

Comment: Oh, there is a slight difference between $T_N x$ and I said at the beginning. I were doing $n\times n$ truncation of the infinite matrix and the hint says it's $\infty\times n$. Anyway let's stick to your hint. Originally with infinitely many terms, it should be $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j$ and if you truncate $x$ to the first $N$ terms, the sum becomes $\sum_{k=1}^N a_{ij}x_j$ as in your hint

Comment: You can use Cauchy-Schwarz to show that $T_N$ is bounded.

Comment: I have taken this proposition: "The series $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} a_{n} b_{n}$ converges absolutely for every convergent sequence $\{b_{n}\}$ iff $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} |a_{n}|$ converges." will it be helpful here in our case? the problem is that here in our case we are in $l^2.$@user58955

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's show a simpler version (1-dimensional): If $\sum_i a_i x_i < \infty$ all for $x\in\ell^2$, then $a\in \ell^2$.

You can prove this claim using uniform boundedness principle, or you can just use Riesz Representation Theorem. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608684/show-that-if-sum-x-n-y-n-converges-for-all-y-y-n-n-in-ell-2-then).

Now, let's go back to your problem. It follows from the claim above that each row of $A$ is in $\ell_2$. Define $T_N$ to be the restriction of $A$ onto the first $N$ rows, that is, 
$$
T_N x = \left(\sum_j a_{1j}x_j,\sum_j a_{2j}x_j,\dots,\sum_j a_{Nj}x_j,0,0,\dots,\right).
$$
We claim that $\|T_N\| < \infty$. Note that
$$
\|T_Nx\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \left|\sum_j a_{ij}x_j\right|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^N\left(\sum_j |a_{ij}|^2 \right)\left(\sum_j |x_j|^2 \right) \leq \|x\|_2^2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|^2,
$$
thus
$$
\|T_N\| \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$
(Note that the infinite sum over $j$ is finite because of the claim at the beginning.)

Now, for each fixed $x$, observe that $\|T_Nx\|_2$ is uniformly bounded by $\|Ax\|_2$ (since $\|T_Nx\|_2$ is just part of the sum for $\|Ax\|_2<\infty$). It follows from the uniform boundedness principle that $\sup_N \|T_N\|<\infty$. Note that $\|Ax\|_2 = \lim_{N\to\infty} \|T_Nx\|_2 \leq (\sup_N \|T_N\|)\|x\|$, which implies that $A$ is bounded and $\|A\| \leq \sup_N \|T_N\|$.

Comment: In this sentence "(Note that the infinite sum over $j$ is finite because of the claim at the beginning.)" do you mean over $j$ or over $i$?

Comment: I mean over $j$. It's $\sum_{j=1}^\infty$, this is an infinite sum

Comment: I think in the 8th line, in your middle term , the $i$ should be until $N.$

Comment: Oh, you're right. Let me fix the typo

Comment: which claim makes the infinite sum over $j$ finite ?I do not understand this.

Comment: I understood now, is this upon taking $x_{i} = 1$ for all $i$?

Comment: and because we have $Ax \in l^2$ for all $x \in l^2$ by assumption ..... am I correct?

Comment: I also have the same question about the infinite sum over $j$ being finite … could you clarify this please?

Comment: @Happy So it's slightly different from your hint. I am taking $T_N$ to be the first $n$ rows of $A$ while in your hint it is the first $n$ columns of $A$. 

No, I am not taking a special $x$ to say $\sum_j |a_{ij}|^2$ is finite. This is from the 1-dimensional version stated at the beginning of the proof. Since $Ax\in \ell^2$, every coordinate of $Ax$ must be finite. The $i$-th coordinate of $Ax$ is $\sum_j a_{ij}x_j$, and this is finite for any $x\in \ell^2$. The 1-dimensional version implies that the $i$-th row of $A$ is in $\ell^2$, that is, $\sum_j |a_{ij}|^2 < \infty$.