# Understanding an application of the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Here is the link to the solution:

[Why should we use the uniform boundedness principle here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3611808/why-should-we-use-the-uniform-boundedness-principle-here/3613496#3613496)

And here is the solution:

First let's show a simpler version (1-dimensional): If $\sum_i a_i x_i < \infty$ all for $x\in\ell^2$, then $a\in \ell^2$.

You can prove this claim using uniform boundedness principle, or you can just use Riesz Representation Theorem. See [this post][1].

Now, let's go back to your problem. It follows from the claim above that each row of $A$ is in $\ell_2$. Define $T_N$ to be the restriction of $A$ onto the first $N$ rows, that is,

$$T_N x = \left(\sum_j a_{1j}x_j,\sum_j a_{2j}x_j,\dots,\sum_j a_{Nj}x_j,0,0,\dots,\right).$$
We claim that $\|T_N\| < \infty$. Note that
$$\|T_Nx\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \left|\sum_j a_{ij}x_j\right|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^N\left(\sum_j |a_{ij}|^2 \right)\left(\sum_j |x_j|^2 \right) \leq \|x\|_2^2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|^2,$$
thus
$$\|T_N\| \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|^2\right)^{1/2}.$$
(Note that the infinite sum over $j$ is finite because of the claim at the beginning.)

Now, for each fixed $x$, observe that $\|T_Nx\|_2$ is uniformly bounded by $\|Ax\|_2$ (since $\|T_Nx\|_2$ is just part of the sum for $\|Ax\|_2<\infty$). It follows from the uniform boundedness principle that $\sup_N \|T_N\|<\infty$. Note that $\|Ax\|_2 = \lim_{N\to\infty} \|T_Nx\|_2 \leq (\sup_N \|T_N\|)\|x\|$, which implies that $A$ is bounded and $\|A\| \leq \sup_N \|T_N\|$.

**But I do not understand this step:**

$\sum_{i=1}^N \left|\sum_j a_{ij}x_j\right|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^N\left(\sum_j |a_{ij}|^2 \right)\left(\sum_j |x_j|^2 \right)$

I know that this is by Cauchy-Schwartz, but should not $a_{ij}x_j$ be inside an absolute value to apply Cauchy Schwartz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the *entire inner product on the LHS* that lies inside the absolute value for Cauchy–Schwarz, not the individual products. The following, which corresponds to what you think is true, is not Cauchy–Schwarz:
$$\langle|\mathbf u|,|\mathbf v|\rangle^2\le\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf u\rangle\langle\mathbf v,\mathbf v\rangle$$
This is the real Cauchy–Schwarz:
$$|\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle|^2\le\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf u\rangle\langle\mathbf v,\mathbf v\rangle$$

Comment: I am unable to get your point of view …. could you please explain it in terms of the terms given in our problem?

Comment: @Mathstupid Here $\mathbf u$ is the vector of $a_{ij}$ for a fixed $i$, and $\mathbf v$ is the vector of $x_j$.