# If Series $\sum \sqrt\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $a_n>0$.
If Series $\sum \sqrt\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges?

My approach:

Ihad used atmost every method like 1)AM and GM inequality
2) cauchy Swartz inequality
3) by definition of convergent series and so on..
I am not able to prove this statement.
I am thinking now this statement is false, neither I am able to find counter example for this.
Any Hint/direction please..

Comment: If $a_n$ decreases here is a posting[Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{{a_{n}}/{n}}$ is convergent. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is also convergent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059124/suppose-sum-n-1-infty-sqrta-n-n-is-convergent-prove-that-sum)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Counterexample: $a_n=1/k$ if $n=k^2$ with $k \in \mathbf{N}$, and $a_n=0$ otherwise. In this case, $\sqrt{a_n/n} = 1/k^{3/2}$ if $n=k^2$ with $k \in \mathbf{N}$, and $\sqrt{a_n/n} = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thankyou so much..

Comment: +1. My counter-example is $a_n=4^{-n}$  if $n$ is not a power of $4$, and $a_n=1$ if $n $ is a power of $4$.  BTW the Q calls for $a_n>0$, unlike your A, but this is easily remedied.