# In an orthogonal sequence is weakly convergent, then it is convergent

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, orthogonality

> Let $ H $ be a Hilbert space, and let $\{x_k \}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthogonal subset of $H$. If for every $y\in H$, $\sum \left<x_k, y\right>$ converges, then $ \sum x_k $ converges too.

I found it as a theorem in functional analysis by Rudin (second edition, section 12.6 pag. 309) but I can't use the Banach-Steinhaus theorem because it is an advanced theorem (I have not seen it yet).  Do you know a simpler proof of this theorem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is some sort of take-home exam, see deleted post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223985/convergent-series-of-orthogonal-vectors-in-hilbert-space

Comment: @WillJagy It's a standard fact in functional analysis, shutting down the discussion of it just because someone on the planet put it on an exam is an overreaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define the partial sum
$$z_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n x_k.$$
Then, we have for $m > n$ (by orthogonality)
$$\|z_m - z_n\|^2 = \left\|\sum_{k = n+1}^m x_k\right\|^2 = \sum_{k = n+1} \|x_k\|^2.$$
Hence, $\{z_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $H$ iff $\{\|x_k\|^2\}$ is summable. Hence, it remains to show that $\{\|x_k\|^2\}$ is summable.

Suppose that $\{\|x_k\|^2\}$ is not summable.
[Then, there is a non-negative sequence $a \in \ell^2$ with $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \, \|x_k\| = +\infty.$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674051/do-non-ell2-sequences-have-an-ell2-functional-that-takes-them-to-infinit)
Now, we set
$$y = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \, \frac{x_k}{\|x_k\|}.$$
(This series converges by $a \in \ell^2$ and orthonormality of $\{x_k/\|x_k\|\}$.)

But,
$$(y, z_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \, \|x_k\|$$
diverges in contradiction with your assumption.