# problem involving series that converges depending on another series converging

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Not sure how to approach this problem below. I tried assuming the conditional but that doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

> If for a sequence of non-negative real numbers $\{a_n\}$, we have $$\sum{a_kb_k}$$ converges whenever $$\sum{b_k^2}$$ converges. then show that $$\sum{a_k^2}$$ converges

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $\sum a_n b_n <\infty$ for all $(b_n)\in \ell^2$ then $(a_n) \in \ell^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37647/if-sum-a-n-b-n-infty-for-all-b-n-in-ell2-then-a-n-in-ell2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the series $a_k^2$ is divergent, put $S_n=\sum_1^n a_k²$. Then $S_n \to +\infty$; hence we may suppose that $S_n>0$ for $n\geq 1$. Put $b_n=\frac{a_n}{S_n }$. Then as
$$b_n^2=\frac{S_{n}-S_{n-1}}{S_n^2}\leq \int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_n}\frac{dt}{t^2}$$ we see that the series $b_n^2$ is convergent. The hypothesis gives now that the series $u_n=\frac{a_n^2}{S_n}=\frac{S_n-S_{n-1}}{S_n}$ is convergent. Hence $u_n\to 0$, and $\frac{S_{n-1}}{S_n}\to 1$. This imply that $u_n$ is equivalent to $v_n=\frac{S_n-S_{n-1}}{S_{n-1}}$, and hence (the two series are positive) the series $v_n$ is convergent. But
$$v_n=\frac{S_n-S_{n-1}}{S_{n-1}}\geq \int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_n}\frac{dt}{t}$$
and this show that the series $v_n$ is divergent, a contradiction.

Comment: Could you explain how the final inequality holds?

Comment: if $S_{n-1}\leq t\leq S_n$, then $\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}\geq \frac{1}{t}$; now integrate this inequality between $S_{n-1}$ and $S_n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum a_kb_k$ and $\sum b_k^2$ converge, then their sum must also converge. Then using AM-GM:
$$\sum b_k(a_k+b_k) \le \frac{1}{2}\sum b_k^2 +\frac{1}{2} \sum (a_k^2+2a_kb_k+b_k^2)<\infty \Rightarrow \sum a_k^2<\infty.$$