# A sequence with finite inner product with any element of $\ell^2$ is itself in $\ell^2$

Tags: hilbert-spaces

$\ell^2$ here is real, not complex. Consider a sequence $x:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$. For any element $y\in\ell^2$, we have $(x,y)_{\ell^2}<\infty$. How do we prove that $x\in\ell^2$? We can assume all the entries of $x$ and $y$ above are nonnegative. If we can show $(x,\cdot)$ is bounded on $\ell^2$, the statement follows from Riesz rep. theorem, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $B_k = \{y \in \ell^2: |(x,y)| \le k\}$.  These are closed, and their union is $\ell^2$.  By the Baire Category Theorem some $B_k$ has nonempty interior.
This implies that $(x, \cdot)$ is bounded.

Comment: The use of the Baire Category theorem always surprises me... (+1 though)

Comment: Thank you very much for an elegant answer! I extensively searched for the duplicate question on SE before posting this question, but I just found it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37647/if-sum-a-n-b-n-infty-for-all-b-n-in-ell2-then-a-n-in-ell2